# How to tell EF Code First to drop only the tables defined with DbSet and not others (Memberhisp tables) in the same database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first, appharbor

I am using EF Code First with `DontDropDbJustCreateTablesIfModelChanged`.


I am using this because I am deploying to Appharbor, and this way only the tables are drop/recreated and not the database. 


In the same database I used the `aspnet_regsql` tool to genarate tables for Membership and Role provider.

How can I make EF Code First to drop/Recreate the tables from my project, and not the ones for  Membership/Role provider?

This is the error i get:

```
Cannot use DROP TABLE with 'vw_aspnet_Applications' because 'vw_aspnet_Applications' is a view. Use DROP VIEW.
Cannot use DROP TABLE with 'vw_aspnet_Users' because 'vw_aspnet_Users' is a view. Use DROP VIEW.
Cannot use DROP TABLE with 'vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers' because 'vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers' is a view. Use DROP VIEW.
Cannot use DROP TABLE with 'vw_aspnet_Roles' because 'vw_aspnet_Roles' is a view. Use DROP VIEW.
Cannot use DROP TABLE with 'vw_aspnet_UsersInRoles' because 'vw_aspnet_UsersInRoles' is a view. Use DROP VIEW.
drop table [vw_aspnet_Applications]
drop table [vw_aspnet_Users]
drop table [vw_aspnet_MembershipUsers]
drop table [vw_aspnet_Roles]
drop table [vw_aspnet_UsersInRoles]]
```

Comment: Did you add the membership tables as a part of your EF model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implement your own IDatabaseInitializer with your own custom logic to exclude these tables (or just not include them)
See an example here:
https://gist.github.com/895730